Unexpected Firestore Query Behavior When Limit Exceeds Item Count
I have a Firestore query that looks like this:
query = query.where(fieldName)
);
this.subscription = query
  .orderBy("time", "desc")
  .endAt(this.firstReference)
  .limit(3);

Let's say I have 3 items in my list: q1, q2, and q3. The firstReference variable is set to q1 (using this.firstReference = querySnapshot.docs[0];)
When I add 3 new items (q11, q12, and q13 (q11 is the oldest item added after q1)) to the list, the query returns the expected output:
q13
q12
q11
-----
q1 (first reference)
q2
q3

Now let's assume instead of 3 I pass 6 items (q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16) (q11 being the oldest item added after q1) when the items present in the list are q1,q1,q3 , The query returns this output:
q16
q15
q14
-----
q1 (first reference)
q2
q3

It should have returned
q13
q12
q11
-----
q1 (first reference)
q2
q3

If I run the query again it should return this output :
q16
q15
q14
-----
q13 (first reference)
q12
q11

Why is the query behavior changing when the number of items returned exceeds the limit, and how can I achieve the desired output?

What do you mean by "the output becomes"? You haven't shown anything that logs any output. It's also not clear why you expect the results of the query to change if you run the query twice, without any of the data changing. (What do you mean by "when I pass 6 items", too?) If you could clarify your question, it would really help...

@JonSkeet I have edited the question for your reference.
My requirement - I want to use a Firestore query to retrieve data in batches of 3 items, where the newest items are displayed at the top, followed by the older items.
q13
q12
q11
q1
q2
q3
Let me know if it's not clear

That's not what queries do though. Your query says (effectively) "give me the last three items". The last three items are q16, q15, q14. Where do you think you're passing enough state for the query to actually mean "give me the first three items that were added since I last performed a query, but in reverse order"?
